# Map Docker run command to dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to integrate my application with Splunk and found a built-in splunk logging driver that requires the below command to be passed in order to work. How can I map the below command to my Dockerfile?

```
docker run \
--log-driver=splunk \
--log-opt splunk-token=176FCEBF\
--log-opt env=TEST \
--env "TEST=false" \
your/application
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk -U upgrade
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR '/workspace'
COPY /workspace/springbootsvc/target/springbootsvc.jar ./springbootsvc.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "springbootsvc.jar"]
```

Comment: ...run it with your image where you see `your/application`?  You need an image to run with the Splunk log driver.

Comment: Many of the `docker run` options can't be forced in the image, and the logging options are among those.